# why consumer has to register with eureka server?

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, feign

I am currenly learning microservices. I have two services Service A and Service B. Service A registered with Eureka server. Service B is calling Service B via Eureka server to get the response. My question is
why Service B has to register with Eureka service in order to call Service A?

Service B can get the Service A url and portno through service discovery from Eureka server. What is the significance of Service B to register with Eureka server?

Comment: Read about it, or at least watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyK5QrKCbwM

Comment: It's a design issue with eureka. It can be turned off with a property setting

Answer (score 2):

Typically in Microservices architecture,  we have a lot of small applications running independently together, and ofcourse they will all have their own URLs and ports.

In that scenario, it would be very cumbersome to maintain all these microservices to run in synchronization, and more importantly, with monitoring. This problem will increase manifold when we start implementing load balancers.

To solve this issue, we need a tool that will monitor and maintain the registry of all the microservices in the ecosystem.

That's why Eureka server acts as directory and service discovery system to make sure they is no direct binding between services and it make sure to have health check for those services.